# IE8 not displaying positioned div correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I am having some trouble with a layout in IE8 only. I have a large background image which is fine. Then I want my header details to sit on top of this. I used absolute positioning with a z-index to get it sitting on top. All other browsers its perfect, only IE8 is giving me problems. Its is positioning my header below the large image.

Here is my code

```
<div id="homepage-banner">
     <img class="home-carousel" src="images/banner.jpg" />
</div>
              <header>
                    <div id="logo">
                            <img src="images/logo.png" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="header-text">
                            <p><span style="font-weight:bold; color: white">></span> Call us now on <strong>0800 785 7348</strong></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:bold; color: white">></span> <a href="#"  style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: black">Click here</a> to enquire online</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav-bar">
                            <img src="images/nav.png"  width="980" height="45"/>
                    </div>
            </header> <!-- header -->
```

And my CSS

```
header {
    height: 120px;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px; }


#homepage-banner {
    height: 555px;
    width: 3000px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
    margin-bottom: -210px;
    background-color: rgb(0,173,239); }
```

How can I change my code so that IE8 displays my header on top of the image?

Comment: Have you included [html5shiv.js](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you haven't included the shiv script because z-index is supported in IE 8. Because you're using the HTML 5 `<header>` element without including the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) script, IE can't parse your header properly, leading to the behavior you describe. Just follow the link I provided and include that script in your `<head>` and you will have support for the new HTML 5 elements ..

Put it in a conditional comment within your `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```